# Как скрыть reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Как можно убрать (или скрыть) reCaptcha и вновь ее показать с помощью js. И как можно с помощью js установить значение для reCAPTCHA (конкретнее: из состояния когда пользователь прошел проверку установить ее значение в состояние, когда пользователь не прошел проверку. Обновить, например, ее отдельно от страницы или может ещё как-нибудь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактировать CSS-свойство `display` или `visibility` с помощью JS.

Comment: "Вносить несущественные правки разрешается только в случаях крайней необходимости."